# Most djangonic solution for Category - Subcategory - Product select form?

Tags: django, forms

Let's suppose we have these three models:

```
 - cagegory    ( id, name ) 
 - subcategory ( id, id_category, name ) 
 - product     ( id, id_sub_category, name )
```

with 30 categories, each category has 30 subcategories and each subcategory has 50 products.

Total products = 30 x 30 x 50 = 45000

Then, in severals views of django project I want to include a product selection.

**What is the most djangonic solution to implement the product selection?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built into Django that's going to solve this use case for you, however, you can use a combination of things in Django to make this work.

I'm assuming you want your product selection to go like this:

- Form has a select drop-down for category.
- User selects category.
- Ajax request sends category id to a view; view returns an html
  string resulting from the rendering of another view that contains
  a drop-down for the sub category, filtered by the category.
- Same process as previous happens, only the sub category id is passed to a view that returns a select for the product, filtered by the sub-category.

You're going to need to use a combination of views, forms and some JavaScript to make this work. There are some nice plugins for jQuery to submit forms via Ajax. Views can return HTML rendered as a string, which you can pop into the DOM, and you should only need one event listener attached to the select(s) that submits their parent form to the URL that will process the POST.

Hope that gets you on the right track.

Comment: as you know, form check that selectec value is on form queryset, what do you think about this? Have you tested this solution that you pourpose?

Comment: I've done exactly the same workflow before. What I did to work around the form validation not recognizing values that were dynamically added was to use separate forms for each dynamically added portion. It's not the most elegant workaround, but if you want to use Django's form classes, I haven't found a better way. Nothing says you have to use form classes here. You can just grab the values from the request.POST collection.

Comment: What do you think about to include only a django hidden input for product and add dinamicaly category, subcategory and product html ajax select binded with django hidden field?

Comment: I'm not sure what the hidden inputs will gain you over just using a select, but whichever way makes the most sense to you, I say go for it :)